# Shortstack SB calling range against UTG

Tags: nlhe, pre-flop, sng

Small home tournament, 6 handed. Full Big blind Ante.

UTG: 16bb

SB (Hero): 9bb

BB: 13bb

UTG shoves 16bb preflop. What should be our calling range?

Hero had AQo, and called to flip against JJ. However, went back to think about it and Hero is mostly dominated in this spot. Can AQo fold here?

Answer (score 4):

In a paid game the immediate question would be what are the payout structure, because it can condition marginal calls into folds if it is relevant to have more chances to finish 2nd.

Second it's a matter of read about how tight is UTG, but AQo is part of top 5%, so it would have to be very tight to make this unprofitable call.

In a winner take all scenario, assuming nothing special about UTG the nash equilibrium calling ranges are [44+ A8s+ ATo+ KQs](https://www.holdemresources.net/nashicm?action=calculate&s1=1600&s2=2000&s3=2000&s4=2000&s5=900&s6=1300&p1=100&p2=0&p3=0&sb=50&bb=100&ante=15), making overall AQo a fairly easy call. It's closer for a 50/30/20 payout structure [but still a call with 55+ ATs+ AJo+](https://www.holdemresources.net/nashicm?action=calculate&s1=1600&s2=2000&s3=2000&s4=2000&s5=900&s6=1300&p1=50&p2=30&p3=20&sb=50&bb=100&ante=15).

It could be that you are being sightly result oriented by the fact UTG has JJ to estimate his range, but UTG actually can profitably push with ATo, KJo, A8s, 22, etc.

Comment: Please help me improve the answer if you feel like it should.

Comment: I put UTG on 99+, AJ+, which AQo has <40% equity against, so its a close fold. UTG is kind of a tight player, although good, so its hard for me to put on a range. For 16 BB it may not be a push/fold strategy also, and may be raise/folding some hands.

Comment: I don't know anything about UTG, but I am pretty sure he would push a hand like A8s or 77. Something is also telling me that he is not shoving 16BB with AA or KK

Comment: @sakon I promise you that 6-handed 16bb UTG shove is much, much wider than 99+, AJ+. It's closer to 22+, A2s+ A9o+, KTs+, Q9s+, QTo+. Even a tight player would push 44+, A4s+, AT+, etc etc.